# Как из программы .NET MAUI передать AssetManager в библиотеку на C++

Tags: c#, android, android-ndk, maui, android-assets

Полученный в C# (MAUI for Android) AssetManager принимается библиотекой, но выдаёт ошибку при попытке воспользовать им. Как правильно передать AssetManager?

C# code:

```
    ...
#if ANDROID        
        [DllImport("library.so", EntryPoint = "SetAsset")]
        public static extern void SetAsset(IntPtr env, Android.Runtime.IJavaObject assetManager);

#endif


void Proc()
{
    var env = JniEnvironment.EnvironmentPointer;  //    JNIEnv *env
    AssetManager assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;   //  jobject 
    SetAsset(env, assets);
}
```

library.so code:

```
void SetAsset(JNIEnv *env, jobject assetManager) 
{
      AAssetManager *pAssetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager); // ERROR in this place
...
}
```

Comment: Ошибка-то какая?

Comment: Ошибку не могу словить. Программа, натыкаясь на AAssetManager *pAssetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);, молча вываливается. Если убрать эту строку в SetAsset(...), то дальше значение из JNIEnv *env берётся и используется без ошибок. Как я понял, что-то не так с передаваемым assetManager.

Comment: Подозреваю, что передаваемый Mono `AssetManager` совсем не `jobject`. Я в Mono не силен, возможно надо `assets.Handle` передавать? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.res.assetmanager